# How to determine if a candle is twice the size for both bullish and bearish

Tags: pine-script

Hi im trying to add something to my code which determines if a candle is greater than twice the  size of a previous candle from open to close of the candle however I cant seem to figure this out for bullish candles and im not entirely sure its working correctly for the bearish. I wanted the candle which is twice the size to highlight yellow.

My code so far is the following however it doesn't seem to be working

```
//@version=4
study(title="vols",overlay=true)
///////////////////////Candles//////////////////////////////////
greenCandle = (close > open)
redCandle   = (close < open)
twoGreenCandles = greenCandle[1] and greenCandle
twoRedCandles   = redCandle[1]   and redCandle
////////////////////////////tick size///////////////////////////
greencandlesize = if greenCandle
    (close/open)/100
redcandlesize = if redCandle
    (close/open)/100
greengo = greencandlesize[1]<greencandlesize
grev = (greencandlesize[1]/100)<((greencandlesize /100)*2)
redgo = redcandlesize[1]>redcandlesize
rev = (redcandlesize[1]/100)>((redcandlesize /100)/2)
///////////////////candle and vol and wicks true////////////////
r = (twoGreenCandles or twoRedCandles) and (grev or rev)
/////////////////////////Color/////////////////////////////////
barcolor(color=r ? color.yellow: na)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is that the canonical way to write comments in pine-script? Ugh... personally, I'd ike to see padding whitespace around operators and inside parenthesis, for general readability.

Comment: my apologies, I'm completely new to coding, only started in the last couple of weeks so that has gone straight over my head

Comment: The idea is to maximize readability. Lines of `////` make for terrible "separators", and the actual comments in there aren't aligned. I am not familiar with pine-script, but unless there is some language-specifics at work, `// comment` should suffice. It is also common practice to have words in variable names either `separated_by_underscore` or `inCamelCase` so the eye has something to latch on to. And finally, many people consider e.g. `( close / open ) / 100` more readable than `(close/open)/100`. Remember, you read code much more often than you write it. Optimize for reading, not writing.

Comment: Thanks Dev you have made some valid points there. much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple script employing the abs() function, some plots, bar color and an alert. Its simply if the candle was twice as big as the last one at the close, then we bar color yellow and can get an alert. There is some plots in hist form so we can see it and measure it if we want. If you want 2 in a row you can add that, but I read it as you wanted either bullish or bearish so wasn't sure. Check it

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

lastCandleSize = abs(close[1]-open[1])
thisCandleSize = abs(close-open)

twiceBig = thisCandleSize >= (lastCandleSize * 2) and barstate.isconfirmed

barcolor(twiceBig ? color.yellow : na)

plot(thisCandleSize, "This candle", color=#5d606b, style=plot.style_columns)
plot(lastCandleSize, "Last candle", color=#d1d4dc, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=4)

alertcondition(twiceBig, title='2x Candle', message='Candle was twice as big on {{interval}} chart. Price is {{close}}')
```